# how to extend the method of a class in a child class without returning all its variables

Tags: python, class, decorator, wrapper

Let's say I have a base class:

```py
class B: 

    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 3
        return 

    def method(self,x):
        y  = 2 * self.b
        x *= 2
        y *= (x + 2)
        return x
```

It does some manipulations based on self.b and produces a variable y that is not returned by method.
Say, I have now a class A which derives from B and will look very similar, but it shall extend the functionality of B's method() by doing additional operations:

```
class A(B) 

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        return 

    def extended_method(self,x):

        x = self.method(x)

        if y<=10: 
            y = 10 

        return x,y

    def what_As_extended_method_should_do(self,x):

        y  = 2 * self.b
        x *= 2
        y *= (x + 2)

        if y<=10: 
            y = 10 

        return x,y
```

extended_method shows the way I'd like to write it, but this will cause an undefined variable error. The method what_As_extended_method_should_do shows what the method should do. But instead of having to write the same code inside B.method() several times (say I have 10 different subclasses which all slightly change B.method(), I would like to have some wrapper that automatically takes B.method()'s y into its scope and can operate on it without undefined variable error. The crux is that I cannot simply return x AND y from B.method(), just x. Does anybody know a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: make `y` instance attribute instead of local (`self.y`)

Comment: `return` in init is uselsss

Comment: You **can** return x and Y from method if you wanted to... Another way you can get around this is if you made y an attribute of B, then you'll have access to it in A too.

Comment: Before we can go any further you need to give us some motivation to recover the value of `y`. At the moment `y` is redundant and should be removed.

Comment: thanks, making y an attribute should actually do the job. i was just thinking about whether there is a method to make functions (maybe even without classes) a wrapper around other functions where the things computed in the inner function are not all returned. but via attribute it definitely works. special thanks to marcin orlowski for your great comment!